# Reload page when countdown reaches 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to combine 2 jQuery functions as per below:

**HTML**

```
<span id="clock" data-countdown="2020/05/16 10:08:00"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

The 1<sup>st</sup> script is counting down from the time in the `data-countdown` attribute to 00:00:

```
var date = $('#clock').data('countdown');

$('#clock').countdown(date, function (event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
});
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> script should reload the page when the time reaches 00:00:

```
var text = document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML;

if (text == '00:00') {
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.reload()
   }, 1000);
}
```

I was trying to combine both the functions, but the page won't refresh when the time reaches 00:00. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/myhub4/pen/LYpgbvr).

```
var date = $('#clock').data('countdown');

$('#clock').countdown(date, function (event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%M:%S'));

    var text = document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML;

    if (text == '00:00') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload()
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are checking the text outside the event handler. The current condition check of `text=='00:00'` will only execute once when the script is loaded.

Here's the working javascript function

```
var date = $('#clock').data('countdown');
$('#clock').countdown(date, function (event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%M:%S'));

  if(document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML === "00:00") {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: Working as expexted, Thank you.